# Django: how to add ckeditor plugins to my project using django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-ckeditor

i want to add some plugins to my ckeditor django, i have installed the package using pip, installed it in settings.py and it's working now, but i want to add some more buttons to the ckeditor as all is have now is bold, align, media, emoji and some more , but i need some feature like code-snippets etc. so where should i add these plugins that i copied from the documentation https://django-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installation

```
a11yhelp, about, adobeair, ajax, autoembed, autogrow, autolink, bbcode, clipboard, codesnippet,
codesnippetgeshi, colordialog, devtools, dialog, div, divarea, docprops, embed, embedbase,
embedsemantic, filetools, find, flash, forms, iframe, iframedialog, image, image2, language,
lineutils, link, liststyle, magicline, mathjax, menubutton, notification, notificationaggregator,
pagebreak, pastefromword, placeholder, preview, scayt, sharedspace, showblocks, smiley,
sourcedialog, specialchar, stylesheetparser, table, tableresize, tabletools, templates, uicolor,
uploadimage, uploadwidget, widget, wsc, xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the sample configuration and extraPlugins: https://django-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#example-ckeditor-configuration

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'skin': 'moono',
        # 'skin': 'office2013',
        'toolbar_Basic': [
            ['Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic']
        ],

...

        'tabSpaces': 4,
        'extraPlugins': ','.join([
            'uploadimage', # the upload image feature
            # your extra plugins here
            'div',
            'autolink',
            'autoembed',
            'embedsemantic',
            'autogrow',
            # 'devtools',
            'widget',
            'lineutils',
            'clipboard',
            'dialog',
            'dialogui',
            'elementspath'
        ]),
    }
}
```